# How to remove exiting code from Heroku as collaborator?

Tags: heroku

I am collaborator on a heroku account owned by someone else  where I accidentally deployed my project .  I don't necessarily want the owner of this account to have access to my source code. And I don't need the code to be there any more. How Can I remove the code from this account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to force push to heroku by overwriting it with new code. Otherwise you can always revert the code to where it was.

If you want to overwrite, here is how to force push.

```
git checkout feature/new-code-to-overwrite
git push --force git@heroku.com:heroku-app-name.git feature/new-code-to-overwrite:master
```